# Meteor collection2 does not validate on the client side

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I am using collection2 with meteor to set default values. However when i run the method `Meteor.call('commands.insert', {})` on the client, it just sets new document's ID, and only when the result from server comes it replaces the document with the right value. Actually, autoValue function runs on client because when i `console.log` there it logs (also tried defaultValue), but it does not do anything, does no modifications, nor `unique: true` is working, any property specified in the schema

server

```
export const Commands = new Mongo.Collection('commands')

Commands.schema = new SimpleSchema({
designation: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        console.log("inssssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeert")
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return "Untitled"
        }
    },
    unique: true
},
name: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return ""
        }
    },
    optional: true
},
syntax: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return ""
        }
    },
    optional: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return ""
        }
    },
    optional: true
},
features: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return ""
        }
    },
    optional: true},
type: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return ""
        }
    },
    optional: true
},
variants: {
    type: Array,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return []
        }
    },
},
'variants.$': {type: String}
})

Commands.attachSchema(Commands.schema)

Meteor.methods({
'commands.insert'(command) {
    if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized')
    }

    Commands.insert(command)
}
})
```

client

```
 const setNewHandler = this.props.page.animationFinished ?
        this.props.page.editing ?
            textEditorData.length ?
                () => {
                    Meteor.call(
                        'commands.update',
                        textEditorData[0]._id,
                        {
                            designation: 
              this.childComponents[0].editableContentNode.textContent,
                            name: 
              this.childComponents[1].editableContentNode.textContent,
                            syntax: 
              this.childComponents[2].editableContentNode.textContent,
                            type: 
              this.childComponents[3].editableContentNode.textContent,
                            variants: 
  this.childComponents[4].editableContentNode.textContent.split("\n"),
                            description: 
              this.childComponents[5].editableContentNode.textContent,
                            features: 
              this.childComponents[6].editableContentNode.textContent
                        }
                    )
                } :
                null :
            () => {

                Meteor.call('commands.insert', {})
            } :
        null
```